# CWWJP0009E error when creating persistence unit

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence.xml, ibm-was

I was facing the following error when starting my Java EE application in IBM WebSphere Application Server WAS 7.

> JPAPUnitInfo  E   CWWJP0009E: The server cannot create an EntityManagerFactory factory for the *NAME_OF_THE_PERSISTENCE_UNIT* persistent unit from the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence provider in file:/C:/*PATH/TO/APPLICATION*/target/classes/ module.

There is certainly something broken in the definition of your persistence unit. You may find the configuration in your `persistence.xml` file. To get more detailed information you have to enable tracing for the server's JPA support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enable tracing in WAS for JPA**

From the main menu of the Application Server's Admin Console choose:

1. Troubleshooting
2. Logs and trace
3. Your server
4. Change log detail levels
5. Switch to one of the two tabs:

   - "Configuration" for a durable change, which are effective after restart
   - "Runtime" for immediately active changes, which are reverted after restart
6. Add messages of all severities from `com.ibm.ws.jpa.*`

Your final trace configuration could look like this:

```
*=info: com.ibm.ws.jpa.*=all
```

This may be active immediately or after restart, depending on your choice above.

Now you find the information to be logged in the server's `trace.log` file, which is stored in the server's log directory. E.g.

> C:\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1

---

**Solution**

The cause of your problem may vary widely. So you have to rely on the diagnosis of your trace file.

However, in my situation I found the following there:

> JPAPUnitInfo  3   Caught unexpected exception:org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.acme.Class1.prop2[com.acme.Class2]

It could be helpful for you, to look out for an `AnnotationException` too. In my case, I added `Class2` to the PU definition in my `persistence.xml`. That worked.

Good luck folks ;-)